# Wavelength filter with OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, filters, computer-vision, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and DSP. I want to code a filter which act like a real optical filter. When you filter the image, the output looks like shotted with a $550nm$ optical filter lens. Like a Bandpass filter for image. I wanna filter all lights below $550nm $ wavelength.

Is it possible with OpenCV? How can Ii do that? Filter2D or Gabor Filter?

Sorry for my English and sorry if the question is irrevelent.

Thanks

Comment: How is your image represented?  RGB?  Luminance/chroma?  Something else?

Comment: So you want to get keep all light above 550 nm and get rid of all light below 550 nm?

Comment: yes my image is rgb and i need all lights above 550 nm

Comment: If you need all colors *above* 550nm, just take the red channel.

Comment: This might prove useful to you: http://www.scientificbulletin.upb.ro/rev_docs_arhiva/full49129.pdf I think it is relevant to the topic of discussion here.

Comment: I think This might prove useful to you :
http://www.cs.utah.edu/~bes/papers/color/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general this is not possible, since you do not have full spectral information for each pixel, but only coordinates in some low-dimensional color space (i.e. RGB).

If your image data is in RGB, then the best you can do is to simply take the green color channel (which will be most responsive to 550 nm) and throw away the red and blue.

Depending on the actual response of your RGB channels, you might be able to better estimate the 550nm contribution via a linear combination of red and green (see [Spectral Sensitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_sensitivity)).

Comment: my image is RGB

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  With signals we don't have all spectral information in a single sample either.  So what?  The spectral information comes from the set of samples, and the set of pixels.

Comment: If we had a very fast *movie* instead of an image, then we could get the (color) spectral information out in the way that you suggest.  But this movie would have to be sampled at optical frequencies, i.e. faster than c/(550 nm)=10^14 Hz.   This is not really possible.

Comment: You can think of an RGB image as being made by passing the light through three bandpass filters (one each for R, G, and B) and recording the power seen in each filtered signal.  Finer-grained (color) spectral information is lost.

Comment: Basically, the color 'dimension' is orthogonal (i.e. not related) to the two spatial dimensions in the image.  So you can't get color information from the spatial distribution of the pixel values.

Comment: @nibot I think I understand- I interpreted "spectral information" in the DFT sense of the term, but you were talking in terms of the original light that the image is a representation of.  Granted we don't have complete knowledge of the original analog "picture", but it seems like he should be able to do something with what he's got.

Comment: thanks your interests. i found this : http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/

Comment: How about this? check every pixel in image and compare RGB-wavelenght values according to that link. if pixels red and green values are upper than value leave pixel else delete (0,0,0) from image? i record image with a ccd camera and images are mostly human faces. i can record a video if it can help some way.

Comment: i found this too :http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ScienceAndEngineering/Spectra.htm

Comment: @juds: This idea is foiled by the existence of non-spectral colors.  It is simply not possible to isolate a given wavelength given RGB values.  However, you can probably achieve the desired effect by converting to HSV color space and selecting a particular range of hues.

Comment: @nibot, I wrote a paper on converting RGB to HSV and then filtering the HSV color coordinates with software lookup tables. Laser light is coherent and single wavelength. How could I use OpenCV to filter green laser pointer beams? Thank you.